# Fetch documents from firebase/ firestore collection

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `'post'` collection in Firestore, in that post collection I have `'post'` documents.

Those post documents are named as the post id. so each name is of random digits and numbers.

The post documents also have quite a few fields like `caption`, `likes`, `UID`, `id`, and etc.

Each post also have more collections, but I specifically want to get access to `"post-replies"` collection. My post replies are basically structured the exact same way as my post with an additional `"replyingTo"` filed.

I want to fetch those replies and load them under the main post. I'm struggling to figure out fetching data on firebase, any pointers to get better would help as well.

Comment: Put your fetching function inside an `ObservableObject` and set a `@Published` property with the results. The Firebase documentation is pretty good about showing how to fetch data -- it's just the SwiftUI part about using an `ObservableObject` part that isn't covered.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know there was firestore documentation by google as im almost completely new to it. I will be reading that now.

Comment: Can you provide your Firestore database structure from firebase console.